# out of proc COM server unable to createobject from asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, com

I have the following setup
WinXP SP2, IIS 5.1

I have an
Asp.net website(a) calling -> Asp.net Webservice(b) calling a function Creating a COM object in an already running EXE server(c).
This COM server works fine with local clients.

The CreateObject fails even when run on a machine when COM server is registered as a user(adminuser) with all privileges on this machine and asp.net is running as ASPNET.

I get Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

If I run the asp.net as a logged in user(adminuser) by chainging "processmodel" in the machine.config with username="adminuser".... then I can make this work

So browser(adminuser)->website(a)->Webservice(b)->CreateObject(c) succeeds

From a different machine, a browser connecting as the same logged in user(adminsuser) fails with Server execution failure.

So browser(adminuser)->website(a)->Webservice(b)->CreateObject(c) fails

If asp.net runs as SYSTEM then I get Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)) even on the local machine.

I am not able to get this to work beyond my local machine. Any insights into settings? Has anyone tried this?

Thanks

Comment: What language is your COM server written with?

Comment: C++, MFC etc. It is a legacy app that is widely used and current COM clients are wokring fine.

Comment: Have you tried to use Dcomcnfg to explicitly give the account the web service appool is running under, permission to create and execute the COM server?